# How should I combine these SQL queries: self-join or use temporary tables?

Tags: sql, self-join, temp-tables

I'm creating a stored procedure pulling aggregate sum values from a few different tables.  Separately, the queries are simplistic with different filters.

The queries need to be joined together and are as follows:

```sql
select distinct(bus_name), sum(act) as 'totrev', sum(budget) as 'budget rev' 
from finance
where year = '2011' 
and type_desc = 'rev'
group by bus_code, bus_name
order by bus_name asc

select distinct(bus_name), sum(act) as 'totalexp', sum(budget) as 'budget exp' 
from finance
where year = '2011' 
and type_desc = 'exp'
group by bus_code, bus_name
order by bus_name asc

select distinct(bus_name), sum(end_balance) as 'total assets' 
from Balance
where year = '2011' 
and type_desc = 'assets'
group by bus_code, bus_name
order by bus_name asc

select distinct(bus_name), sum(end_balance) as 'Cash' 
from Balance
where year = '2011' 
and type_desc = 'equity'
group by bus_code, bus_name
order by bus_name asc

select bus_code, bus_name, count(bus_code) as '#of bldgs'
from building
group by bus_code, bus_name
order by bus_name asc
```

I'm looking to merge/join all the columns to be viewed essentially in one table.
finance_table
columns = bus_code, bus_name, # of bldgs, tot_rev, budget_rev, totalexp, budget exp, total assets, cash

Comment: what output are you looking for?

Comment: I edited the original question to reflect the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this by using nested queries:

```
SELECT T5.bus_code, T5.bus_name, T5.[# of bldgs], T1.tot_rev, T1.budget_rev, T2.totalexp, T2.[budget exp], T3.[total assets], T4.cash
FROM
    (
    select distinct(bus_name), sum(act) as 'totrev', sum(budget) as 'budget rev' 
    from finance
    where year = '2011' 
    and type_desc = 'rev'
    group by bus_code, bus_name
    order by bus_name asc
    ) T1 INNER JOIN
    (
    select distinct(bus_name), sum(act) as 'totalexp', sum(budget) as 'budget exp' 
    from finance
    where year = '2011' 
    and type_desc = 'exp'
    group by bus_code, bus_name
    order by bus_name asc
    ) T2 ON T1.bus_name = T2.bus_name
    INNER JOIN
    (
    select distinct(bus_name), sum(end_balance) as 'total assets' 
    from Balance
    where year = '2011' 
    and type_desc = 'assets'
    group by bus_code, bus_name
    order by bus_name asc
    ) T3 ON T2.bus_name = T3.bus_name
    INNER JOIN
    (
    select distinct(bus_name), sum(end_balance) as 'Cash' 
    from Balance
    where year = '2011' 
    and type_desc = 'equity'
    group by bus_code, bus_name
    order by bus_name asc
    ) T4 ON T3.bus_name = T4.bus_name
    INNER JOIN
    (
    select bus_code, bus_name, count(bus_code) as '#of bldgs'
    from building
    group by bus_code, bus_name
    order by bus_name asc
    ) T5 ON T4.bus_name = T5.bus_name
```

I assume inner joins, but you may need to use outer joins if some of these won't have an entry for a particular business.  But the general technique would be the same.

Comment: Thanks Shawn this helped a lot.  I need to bring back all of the business names in which some do not have expenses and revenues.  District code is unique and I believe that would require a left join.  Can you direct me to how to adjust the syntax?

Comment: I've actually managed to adjust my query to bring back some of the business names that I was not getting previously through outer joins but not all.  There are businesses with duplicate names but all with unique codes.  Running the #of bldgs query seperately still produces more rows than I have been able to retrieve through the nested joins.  These business names that are not being retrieved have null values for all columns accept #of bldgs.

Answer (score 1):

If your SQL supports CASE expressions, you can use them to create "virtual" fields for each type, and then sum these up.

```
select bus_code, bus_name
 ,sum(case when type_desc = 'rev' then act else 0 end) as 'totrev'
 ,sum(case when type_desc = 'rev' then budgetelse 0 end) as 'budget rev' 
 ,sum(case when type_desc = 'exp' then act else 0 end) as 'totexp'
 ,sum(case when type_desc = 'exp' then budgetelse 0 end) as 'budget exp' 
 ... ... etc.
from finance
where year = '2011' 
group by bus_code, bus_name
order by bus_name asc
```

The last (building) table can simple be joined to this one, on bus-code